# Retrieving Common and Unique Element from JsonArray

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON in this format

```
[
    {"ip":"190","params":{"key":"Thread_State","value":"start"}},
    {"ip":"190","params":{"key":"Rate_Classification","value":"30"}},
    {"ip":"190","params":{"key":"Rate_Evaluation","value":"30"}},
    {"ip":"191","params":{"key":"Thread_State","value":"start"}}, 
    {"ip":"191","params":{"key":"Thread_State","value":"stop"}}
]
```

and I want to retrieve common and unique elements from this JSON based on key and value.

For example :

The common Elements are {"ip":190`{"key":Thread_State,"value":start}`},{"ip":191`{"key":Thread_State,"value":start}`}

How do we get this result using JavaScript ?

Comment: where is json format???

Comment: @kishore Is this an array of elements?  Show the full object.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var json_string ='[{"ip":"190","params":{"key":"Thread_State","value":"start"}},{"ip":"190","params":{"key":"Rate_Classification","value":"30"}},{"ip":"190","params":{"key":"Rate_Evaluation","value":"30"}},{"ip":"191","params":{"key":"Thread_State","value":"start"}},{"ip":"191","params":{"key":"Thread_State","value":"stop"}}]';
var dataArray = [];
var encoded = jQuery.parseJSON(json_string);
$.each(encoded, function (index, value) {
    dataArray.push([value["ip"].toString(), value["params"]["key"], value["params"]["value"] ]);
});
alert(dataArray);
</script>
```

Comment: you want value  of json object or json format as you have written in question.

Comment: I need that result in Json

Comment: I am looking into underscore.js

Comment: if you want result as json like "{"ip":190{"key":Thread_State,"value":start}},{"ip":191{"key":Thread_State,"value":start}}".. then you should modify your sql query from where you are getting this json..